# Non-commuting matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

Reading [this book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Quantum_physics_in_one_dimension.html?id=GVeuKZLGMZ0C&redir_esc=y), I came across the following formula

$$e^A e^B = e^{A+B}e^{\frac{1}{2}[A,B]}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are two matrices and $[A,B] := AB-BA$.

I tried to find a proof, without success. It is impossible to use the binomial theorem since $A$ and $B$ do not commute. I've thought about developping the product in a power series, but I'm not sure the Cauchy product is allowed when $[A,B] \ne 0$.

I thought that $[A,B^k]$ could be useful so I searched the general expression

$$[A,B^n] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B^i [A,B] B^{n-i-1}$$

Does anyone know a proof of the formula above? If so, is it possible to provide some hints? Or a full proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author probably means an approximation rather than a true equality, as $(A+B)+\frac12[A,B]$ are only the first two terms in the <s>[BCH formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)</s> [Zassenhaus formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: How can one be sure that the terms after can be neglected ?

Comment: @ChocoPouce The trailing terms are not always negligible. You may search the internet for convergence results. For example, see sec. 3 and fig. 1 of Casas *et al.*, [Efficient computation of the Zassenhaus formula](http://www.gicas.uji.es/Fernando/MyPapers/CPC2012.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

The equality is true when $A,B$ are quasi-commutative, that is, when $[A,B]$ commutes with both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 4):

The book you referenced was "Quantum Physics in One Dimension". The operators in quantum mechanics have to obey particular commutation relations. For instance the operators $x$ and $p$ obey the canonical commutation relation,

$$ \left[ x, p \right] = i I. $$

This allows us to simplify the Zassenhaus formula. The operator $[x,p]$ commutes with every operator because it is proportional to the identity; if you consider the higher order terms in the Zassenhaus formula you will see they involve commutators which must be zero.

Meaning that,

$$\exp(x+p)= \exp(x)\exp(p)\exp(-[x,p]/2),$$

is an exact relationship for the operators $x$ and $p$.

Knowledge of specific commutation relations can allow you to simplify the Zassenhaus formula significantly.